# Is there a better way to cut the Size height and Width in System.Drawing.Size in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, resize

Right now I have a method I pass the image Size to called ResizeIfLargeImage if the size of an image is too large I divide the size by 2. Here is the code below.

```
private Size ResizeIfLargeImage(Size resizeIfLargeImage){
If((resizeIfLargeImage.Height>1000)||(resizeIfLargeImage.Width>1000))
{
resizeIfLargeImage.Height = resizeIfLargeImage.Height/2;
resizeIfLargeImage.Width = resizeIfLargeImage.Width/2;

return ResizeIfLargeImage(resizeIfLargeImage);
}
else
{
return resizeIfLargeImage;
}

}
```

Basically, I did a little recursion just in case the image size is still too large it will keep cutting the size in half until its width or height are under 1000 px. I think my code isn't right especially in software development to avoid hardcoded values. I wanted to know if there was a better way to cut the height and width in half in .NET if the Size of the image is too large any help or suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is. Calculate a scale factor to reduce the image size in one go.

```cs
private Size ResizeIfLargeImage(Size imageSize){
    const int MaxSize = 1000;

    int maxLength = Math.Max(imageSize.Height, imageSize.Width);
    if(maxLength > MaxSize) {
        double scaleFacor =  (double)MaxSize / maxLength;
        imageSize.Height = (int)Math.Round(scaleFactor * imageSize.Height);
        imageSize.Width = (int)Math.Round(scaleFactor * imageSize.Width);
    }
    return imageSize;
}
```